# How to test whether a float is a whole number in Go?

Tags: go, modulus

I originally tried this, however the % operator isn't defined for float64.

```
func main(){
    var a float64
    a = 1.23
    if a%1 == 0{
        fmt.Println("yay")
    }else{
        fmt.Println("you fail")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Assuming that your numbers will fit into an `int64`, you can compare the float value with a converted integer value to see if they're the same:

```golang
if a == float64(int64(a)) { ... }
```

Alternatively, if you need the entire `float64` domain, you can use [the `math.Trunc` function](http://golang.org/pkg/math/#Trunc), with something like:

```golang
if a == math.Trunc(a) { ... }
```

For example, the following code correctly outputs `yay`, on testing over at [the Go playground](https://go.dev/play/):

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

func main() {
    var a float64 = 2.00
    if a == math.Trunc(a) {
        fmt.Println("yay")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("you fail")
    }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't seem like a well-typed Go expression.  Go insists that both operands to `==` be of the exact same type.

Comment: In fact, having tried it, it is rejected as not-well-typed for the aforementioned reasons.  One would need to cast back to float first.

Comment: As with Deepu's answer this fails when the integer part of the expression is over 2^63. @TimStClair and @Gian have the idea (keep it a float, but use `math` to separate the int and fractional part).

Comment: @twotwotwo, yes, it will. That's why I have the bit about it being suitable for numbers within the range of an int64, and why I provided a link to the truncate function for situations where you want to use the full range. I'm not sure if you just missed that final paragraph or not so, if you have an issue that's not already covered in the anwser or if I've misunderstood (entirely possible), please let me know and I'll try to fix it up.

Comment: D'oh, sorry, I did miss that last sentence. Casting still isn't what I'd suggest even spelling out the issue with it, but yes, my comment was redundant.

Comment: No probs, @twotwotwo, just wanted to make sure I hadn't missed something. Cheers.

Comment: The second example is wrong. If a is equal to 2.00, the code fails.

Comment: @ZottoSL: I just checked that, and I've added the code I used to the answer. It *does* actually seem to work correctly for `2.00`. I'm not sure what method you're using to test but, if you let me know, I can try nut it out.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [`math.Modf`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/#Modf) function:

```
const epsilon = 1e-9 // Margin of error
if _, frac := math.Modf(math.Abs(a)); frac < epsilon || frac > 1.0 - epsilon {
    // ...
}
```

`epsilon` is necessary here since floating point math is not precise (e.g. [`float64(.3)+float64(.6)+float64(.1) != 1`](https://play.golang.org/p/zjm00IO5z2))

From the godoc:

> ```
> func Modf(f float64) (int float64, frac float64)
> ```
>
> Modf returns integer and fractional floating-point numbers that sum to f. Both values have the same sign as f.

Comment: Because [floating point results usually aren't exact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems) I would use `Modf` but check if the number is _close_ to an integer, [like this](http://play.golang.org/p/uUZCt0brgl). Otherwise `float64(.3)+float64(.6)+float64(.1)` will be treated as a noninteger.

Comment: (Note that the types in that sample "bad" float value are necessary to see the problem because Go [goes to extra trouble to make math on untyped constants more precise](https://blog.golang.org/constants).)

Answer (score 0):

How about [math.Trunc](http://golang.org/pkg/math/#Trunc)?  It truncates a `float64` to its whole-number component.

For example, something like:

```
if a.Trunc() == a {
    // ...
}
```

Beware of the usual considerations about floating-point representation limitations.  You might wish to check whether `a.Trunc()` is within some small range of `a`, to account for values like `1.00000000000000002`.

Comment: Looks close, but it's `math.Trunc(a)` not `a.Trunc()`. Whole corrected `if` is something like `if aa := math.Trunc(a)-a; aa < 1e-5 && aa > -1e-5 {...}`

Comment: Incomplete answer.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like so:

```
isWhole := int(value * 100) == int(value) * 100
```

Adjust the number of digits in the factor, e.g. multiply by 10000 to check 4 digits.

Answer (score 0):

Just **ceil** or **float** your number and compare the result to origin value.
The best solution for me:

```golang
var a float64 = 2.11
var b float64 = 3.00

fmt.Println(math.Ceil(a) == a) // 3.00 == 2.11; false; a is not a whole number
fmt.Println(math.Ceil(b) == b) // 3.00 == 3.00; true; b is a whole number
```

You can use a function:

```golang
func isWhole(x float64) bool {
  return math.Ceil(x) == x
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the following code might be useful,

```
func main(){
    var (
          a float64
          b float64
          c float64
    ) 
    a = 1.23
    b = float64(int64(a))
    c = a - b
    if c > 0 {
        fmt.Println("Not a Whole Number")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Whole Number")
    }
}
```

Comment: There seems to be a danger of overflowing `b` here?

Comment: The problem is that `a` is a `float64` that is being coerced to an `int`, at which point it may overflow the (32-bit) `int` type and result in a wacky loss of precision (or indeed, a false negative).

Comment: Still overflows for, e.g. 1e30, just now the overflow is in the temporary value used in the calculation of `b`. Gian's and Tim St. Clair's answers seem like the approach (and Tim's compiles and shows how to handle rounding error, so it's my pick).